# “Edit” option for custom post types archive page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

How do I add "Edit" in archive-products.php (Products Post Type page)? At the moment there is no editor in archive-products.php see screenshot:

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I use a CPT UI for archive, tax etc

Comment: Are you asking 'Edit' link in front-end for 'Products Category' pages? Can you let me know the taxonomy name & custom post type name?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress Yes I would like to have edit in Products page frontend to add content, custom post type is products and taxomomy name is product_category thanks :)

Comment: Like this one: http://bubblei.co.uk/zJ6veu.png

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your taxonomy file to show the edit taxonomy link - `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_edit_term_link( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'product_category', '' ) ); ?>">Edit Taxonomy</a>`.

Add this code in your single post file to show the edit post link - `<?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?>`.

Comment: Thanks but there is no editor content for /products/ (post type)

Comment: Are you saying content editor not appearing in WordPress admin panel for Products edit page?

Comment: Okay, can you share your `register_post_type()` function for Products?

Comment: You might miss the `supports` parameter - add this to your `register_post_type()` function - `'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor')`.

Comment: See screenshots: http://bubblei.co.uk/va3No9.png and http://bubblei.co.uk/Y4sprm.png

Comment: Its already in there: "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),

Comment: Your code is fine, can you confirm whether editor not showing in Products or Product Category? Also, can you share your `register_taxonomy()` code?

Comment: Can you confirm whether editor not showing in Products or Product Category?

Comment: Editor not showing in Products, Product Category have editor but not Products (Post Type)

Comment: All your codes are fine, so there are chances for some conflicts. Try deactivating all the plugins, switch to default theme and try again.

Comment: I default theme and deactivating all the plugin but still not shown editor content in Product page. See screenshot to help you understand what I mean: http://bubblei.co.uk/CajMLZ.png Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot add an editor over there. Instead create a page with title 'Products', add your code as a template, assign that to the new page. You can simply add `the_content()` in the template to display the content followed by products list loop.

Comment: Please note that you need to write custom query to list the products in the new template file, check this for the code - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/query-for-custom-post-type